# configure(HttpSecurity http) and configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder) get ignored with certain annotations in WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security

I'm trying to secure my spring application that has  different user roles. While the Authentication part is set and works flawlessly, I realised during the implementation of the Authorisation part that with certain annotations, one of the two overrides methods inside my `SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class`, gets ignored.

```
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  private WebApplicationContext applicationContext;
  private CredentialsService userDetailsService;

  @Autowired
  private DataSource dataSource;

  @PostConstruct
  public void completeSetup() {
    userDetailsService =   applicationContext.getBean(CredentialsService.class);
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .permitAll()
            .and()

            .httpBasic()
            .disable()

            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/admin", "/admin/**")
            .hasRole("ADMIN")
            .and()

            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/employee", "/employee/**")
            .hasRole("EMPLOYEE")
            .and()

            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/customer", "/customer/**")
            .hasRole("CUSTOMER");
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(encoder())
            .and()
            .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
            .jdbcAuthentication()
            .dataSource(dataSource);
  }


  @Bean
  public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
    final DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(encoder());
    return authProvider;
  }

  @Bean
  public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(12);
  }
}
```

Now the problem is the following, as it is, this class authenticate my users but has one major drawback: the

```
configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
```

gets completely ignored.

On the other side though, if I add the @Configuration annotation on top of my class, the

```
protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
```

gets completely ignored, hence will break the authorisation as it won't be able to call the getUsername() and getPassword on my custom `UserDetailsService` implementation.

As you can see, I've used a `DaoAuthenticationProvider` instance as authenticationProvider, since my application retrieve the users/password from an external database.

The quick fix I adopted right now it's the addition of the following method on my main class

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        securedEnabled = true,
        jsr250Enabled = true,
        prePostEnabled = true
)
```

and the use of the `@Secured` annotation on my restricted controllers. That works, but I'd like to understand why Spring has such strange behaviour and what step can I take to address these problems.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are assigning roles to your users, use the syntax

```java
.antMatchers("/admin", "/admin/**")
.hasRole("ADMIN")
```

OR

```java
.antMatchers("/admin", "/admin/**")
.hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")
```

Roles are just stored as authorities with the "ROLE_" prefix.
So the role "ADMIN" is equivalent to the authority "ROLE_ADMIN".

EDIT 1

You can also simplify your configuration to make it clear where everything is coming from.

Since you `UserDetailsService` (`CredentialsService`) is already a bean, it will be picked up automatically by Spring Security.

```java
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  // The password encoder should be a bean
  @Bean
  public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(12);
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .permitAll()
            .and()

            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/admin", "/admin/**")
            .hasRole("ADMIN")
            .and()

            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/manager", "/manager/**")
            .hasRole("MANAGER")
            .and()

            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/customer", "/customer/**")
            .hasRole("CUSTOMER");
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you Eleftheria, I tried but unfortunately doesn't work, the users are still allowed to access restricted controllers.

Comment: @WebStormer I've updated my answer to a simplified configuration you can try

Comment: Eleftheria Stein-Kousathana I found the where the issues is and I re-written the question, feel free to have a look!